# Unable to resolve host "xyz.com": No address associated with hostname after adding "INTERNET" permission

Tags: android

java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xyz.com": No address associated with hostname

I found this issue,While trying to fetch data through web service. I have given "INTERNET" permission in manifest. also my WiFi connection works fine.
This issue is not often, Sometime this hostname works and I will get data through same web service, but sometime it give this error.

Comment: restart wifi and try and add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> in manifest if not added

Comment: I already have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> permission. Not working yet

Comment: restart wifi and try

Comment: If reconnecting the WiFi doesn't work for you, try reboot your device.

Comment: try it by adding  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> premission

Answer (score 5):

You just need to take into consideration that if you are working with an emulator, either Android Studio's Android Emulator or Genymotion Emulator, **you just need to restart it** if you have been working with it and you haven't restarted it after a wake up from your computer.

TL;DR -> every time you leave an emulator session open even after an hibernation of your computer and you need to work with Internet, it's **highly recommended to restart the emulator** to avoid spending time trying to debug the problem.